# Passing AJAX variables to a Jquery ui dialog on the same page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Right now I've got a ui dialog on a page, and I need some way to pass a javascript variable to the php within the dialog via AJAX. Here's my code:

```
$('.user').click(function(){
    var user = getID($(this).attr('id'),'User');
    $.ajax({   
        type: "POST",   
        url: "test.php",   
        data: 'user=' + user,
        success: function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog('open');
        }
    });
});
```

and the beginning of the PHP:

```
    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['user'])){
            echo '<center><b>User: '.ucfirst($_POST['user']).'</b></center><br />';
        }
```

The problem is, it's just not getting passed. I'm very new with Ajax so I'm sure I'm messing something up.

Comment: What is the value of "user" before the AJAX call?

Comment: I second Jon on making sure the user var has the intended value before using it in the ajax call

Comment: when I do alert(user), i get the correct string

Comment: Could this all possibly be because my php loads before the ajax is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working because you don't specify the return variable, see your code with correction:

```
$('.user').click(function(){
var user = getID($(this).attr('id'),'User');
$.ajax({   
    type: "POST",   
    url: "test.php",   
    data: 'user=' + user,
    success: function(data){ // Here you specify the callback variable from the AJAX call
        alert(data); // Here will show '<center><b>User: UserExample </b></center><br />';
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make your dialog content my loading some page like Userpage.php and then pass User as  a url parameter

```
$('.user').click(function(){
    var user = getID($(this).attr('id'),'User');
    $.ajax({   
        type: "POST",   
        url: "test.php",   
        data: 'user=' + user,
        success: function(){
            $("#dialog").load('/userpage.php?User=' + user).dialog('open');
        }
    });
});
```